# Copy and paste text with comments

Tags: google-docs, google-drive-comments

I've got 2 Google Drive documents that have comments in them, made using the comments tool.

I'd like to copy and paste text along with its comments between these 2 documents. Is that possible?

Comment: It's important to send this kind of feedback in google doc/feedback "feature request: please let us Copy and paste text with comments"

Answer (score 2):

The only way how to copy comments between documents is:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

I downloaded the document to excel. There I used ["How To Easily Extract Comments Contents In Excel?"](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/5122-excel-extract-comments.html) vbscript to extract the text from the comments